# If Horner’s rule is used what is the number of multiplications to compute P(n) for an polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Let P(x)=3x^2 + 4x + 2 be a polynomial in the variable x. If Horner’s rule is used, what is the number of multiplications to compute P(10)

Comment: Isn't it $2$, the degree of the polynomial?

Comment: Sorry I cant understand What is $2$ can you please tell me the final answer I mean number of multiplications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horner'rule uses the following method: For $P(x) = 2 + 4x + 3x^2$, $a_0 = 2, a_1 = 4, a_2 = 3$, and $x_0 = 10$. In general, you calculate the new finite sequence $b_n = a_n$, $b_{n-1} = a_{n-1} + b_n \cdot x_0$,
$...$, $b_0 = a_0 + b_1 \cdot x_0$, and $b_0$ is the value of $P(x_0)$. So in this question, $b_2 = a_2 = 3$, $b_1 = 4 + 3 \cdot 10$ = $34$, and $b_0 = 2 + 34 \cdot 10 = 342$, and the number of multiplications is $2$.

Comment: Sorry I cant understand What is $2$ can you please tell me the final answer I mean number of multiplications?

Comment: @user3452098: 2 = the # of multiplications that must be carried out to get the answer.

Comment: Can you please solve this in an non confusing way ? and tell me exact answer to this question .

Comment: $3x^2+4x+2 = 2 + x\cdot(3\cdot x + 4)$ - now count the number of dots. Two.

Answer (score 0):

Horner's method works as follows. Given a polynomial $P(x)$ which you wish to evaluate at the point $x_0$, you rewrite $P(x)$ as $P(x) = (x-x_0)Q(x) + b_0$. Naturally, we have $P(x_0) = (x_0 - x_0)Q(x) + b_0 = b_0$.

There are many way to obtain $Q(x)$ that all require different numbers of operations. Hopefully this gives you a starting point.

Comment: This is just Ruffini's rule. Horner is the table to do manual computation of the value.

Comment: Sorry I cant understand What is $Q(x)$ can you please tell me the final answer I mean number of multiplications?